# Hangfire call method in class

Tags: hangfire

I want to convert `QUARTZ` jobs to `hangfire`

There I have a class with `Execute` method.

How to call this method in Hangfire. I try something like

```
public static string CRON_EXP = "0 30 1 ? * *";
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("CheckStudentAgeJob", () => CheckStudentAgeJob(), CRON_EXP);
```

class is

```
public class CheckStudentAgeJob {
    public void Execute()
    {
          //...
    }
}
```

but syntax is not correct. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call a class instead of a method. It should be:

```
public static string CRON_EXP = "0 30 1 ? * *";
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("CheckStudentAgeJob", 
                         () => new CheckStudentAgeJob().Execute(), CRON_EXP);
```